# What is the effect of applying setCellStyle to an org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell multiple times?

Tags: java, excel, spreadsheet

The documentation I've found doesn't address this issue.  I would think that calling cell.setCellStyle(a) and cell.setCellStyle(b) would completely overwrite style a and apply style b instead.  However, it appears that it is applying both because the styles don't conflict.  Is this expected behavior or magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's the source code for `setCellStyle()`:

```
 public void setCellStyle(CellStyle style) {
     if(style == null) {
         if(_cell.isSetS()) _cell.unsetS();
     } else {
         XSSFCellStyle xStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)style;
         xStyle.verifyBelongsToStylesSource(_stylesSource);

         long idx = _stylesSource.putStyle(xStyle);
         _cell.setS(idx);
     }
 }
```

`_cell` is of type `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCell` and I couldn't find the source code online.  However, since the call to `_cell.setS(idx)` passes in just an index, the API doesn't look rich enough to support merging of styles.  I strongly suspect your second style has all the attributes you are seeing.